# Unable to verify that GCS bucket exists while creating and staging Dataflow template

Tags: java, maven, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I am creating and staging gcp dataflow template in cloud storage with following command:

mvn -X compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=main.java.TemplatePipeline -Dexec.args="--runner=DataflowRunner --project=hv-hcap-development --stagingLocation=gs://my-bucket/staging --templateLocation=gs://my-bucket/templates/template1"

The build is failing with following error:

```
[INFO]
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (default-cli) @ ingestion-streaming ---
[WARNING]
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to verify that GCS bucket gs://ingestion-streaming exists.
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.storage.GcsPathValidator.verifyPathIsAccessible (GcsPathValidator.java:86)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.storage.GcsPathValidator.validateOutputFilePrefixSupported (GcsPathValidator.java:53)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.fromOptions (DataflowRunner.java:285)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.buildFromMethod (InstanceBuilder.java:217)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.build (InstanceBuilder.java:158)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.PipelineRunner.fromOptions (PipelineRunner.java:55)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.create (Pipeline.java:155)
    at com.ford.datafactory.ingestion.streaming.StreamingPipeline.main (StreamingPipeline.java:41)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:282)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error getting access token for service account: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.refreshAccessToken (ServiceAccountCredentials.java:612)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.refresh (OAuth2Credentials.java:164)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.getRequestMetadata (OAuth2Credentials.java:149)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.getRequestMetadata (ServiceAccountCredentials.java:946)
    at com.google.auth.http.HttpCredentialsAdapter.initialize (HttpCredentialsAdapter.java:91)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.ChainingHttpRequestInitializer.initialize (ChainingHttpRequestInitializer.java:52)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestFactory.buildRequest (HttpRequestFactory.java:91)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.buildHttpRequest (AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:404)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed (AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:514)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed (AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:455)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute (AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:565)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.ResilientOperation$AbstractGoogleClientRequestExecutor.call (ResilientOperation.java:171)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.ResilientOperation.retry (ResilientOperation.java:67)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.util.GcsUtil.getBucket (GcsUtil.java:489)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.util.GcsUtil.bucketAccessible (GcsUtil.java:477)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.util.GcsUtil.bucketAccessible (GcsUtil.java:450)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.storage.GcsPathValidator.verifyPathIsAccessible (GcsPathValidator.java:83)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.storage.GcsPathValidator.validateOutputFilePrefixSupported (GcsPathValidator.java:53)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.fromOptions (DataflowRunner.java:285)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.buildFromMethod (InstanceBuilder.java:217)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.build (InstanceBuilder.java:158)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.PipelineRunner.fromOptions (PipelineRunner.java:55)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.create (Pipeline.java:155)
    at com.ford.datafactory.ingestion.streaming.StreamingPipeline.main (StreamingPipeline.java:41)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:282)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:834)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException (Alert.java:131)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal (TransportContext.java:369)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal (TransportContext.java:312)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal (TransportContext.java:307)
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts (CertificateMessage.java:1357)
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate (CertificateMessage.java:1232)
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume (CertificateMessage.java:1175)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume (SSLHandshake.java:392)
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch (HandshakeContext.java:478)
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch (HandshakeContext.java:456)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch (TransportContext.java:199)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode (SSLTransport.java:171)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode (SSLSocketImpl.java:1369)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord (SSLSocketImpl.java:1278)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake (SSLSocketImpl.java:401)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake (SSLSocketImpl.java:373)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect (HttpsClient.java:567)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect (AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:197)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0 (HttpURLConnection.java:1367)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream (HttpURLConnection.java:1342)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream (HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:246)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute (NetHttpRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute (NetHttpRequest.java:84)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute (HttpRequest.java:1012)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.refreshAccessToken (ServiceAccountCredentials.java:609)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.refresh (OAuth2Credentials.java:164)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.getRequestMetadata (OAuth2Credentials.java:149)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.getRequestMetadata (ServiceAccountCredentials.java:946)
    at com.google.auth.http.HttpCredentialsAdapter.initialize (HttpCredentialsAdapter.java:91)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.ChainingHttpRequestInitializer.initialize (ChainingHttpRequestInitializer.java:52)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestFactory.buildRequest (HttpRequestFactory.java:91)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.buildHttpRequest (AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:404)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed (AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:514)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed (AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:455)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute (AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:565)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.ResilientOperation$AbstractGoogleClientRequestExecutor.call (ResilientOperation.java:171)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.ResilientOperation.retry (ResilientOperation.java:67)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.util.GcsUtil.getBucket (GcsUtil.java:489)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.util.GcsUtil.bucketAccessible (GcsUtil.java:477)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.util.GcsUtil.bucketAccessible (GcsUtil.java:450)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.storage.GcsPathValidator.verifyPathIsAccessible (GcsPathValidator.java:83)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.storage.GcsPathValidator.validateOutputFilePrefixSupported (GcsPathValidator.java:53)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.fromOptions (DataflowRunner.java:285)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.buildFromMethod (InstanceBuilder.java:217)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.build (InstanceBuilder.java:158)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.PipelineRunner.fromOptions (PipelineRunner.java:55)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.create (Pipeline.java:155)
    at com.ford.datafactory.ingestion.streaming.StreamingPipeline.main (StreamingPipeline.java:41)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:282)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:834)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild (PKIXValidator.java:439)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate (PKIXValidator.java:306)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate (Validator.java:264)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate (X509TrustManagerImpl.java:313)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted (X509TrustManagerImpl.java:222)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted (X509TrustManagerImpl.java:129)
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts (CertificateMessage.java:1341)
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate (CertificateMessage.java:1232)
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume (CertificateMessage.java:1175)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume (SSLHandshake.java:392)
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch (HandshakeContext.java:478)
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch (HandshakeContext.java:456)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch (TransportContext.java:199)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode (SSLTransport.java:171)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode (SSLSocketImpl.java:1369)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord (SSLSocketImpl.java:1278)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake (SSLSocketImpl.java:401)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake (SSLSocketImpl.java:373)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect (HttpsClient.java:567)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect (AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:197)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0 (HttpURLConnection.java:1367)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream (HttpURLConnection.java:1342)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream (HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:246)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute (NetHttpRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute (NetHttpRequest.java:84)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute (HttpRequest.java:1012)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.refreshAccessToken (ServiceAccountCredentials.java:609)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.refresh (OAuth2Credentials.java:164)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.getRequestMetadata (OAuth2Credentials.java:149)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.getRequestMetadata (ServiceAccountCredentials.java:946)
    at com.google.auth.http.HttpCredentialsAdapter.initialize (HttpCredentialsAdapter.java:91)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.ChainingHttpRequestInitializer.initialize (ChainingHttpRequestInitializer.java:52)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestFactory.buildRequest (HttpRequestFactory.java:91)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.buildHttpRequest (AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:404)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed (AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:514)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed (AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:455)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute (AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:565)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.ResilientOperation$AbstractGoogleClientRequestExecutor.call (ResilientOperation.java:171)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.ResilientOperation.retry (ResilientOperation.java:67)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.util.GcsUtil.getBucket (GcsUtil.java:489)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.util.GcsUtil.bucketAccessible (GcsUtil.java:477)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.util.GcsUtil.bucketAccessible (GcsUtil.java:450)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.storage.GcsPathValidator.verifyPathIsAccessible (GcsPathValidator.java:83)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.storage.GcsPathValidator.validateOutputFilePrefixSupported (GcsPathValidator.java:53)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.fromOptions (DataflowRunner.java:285)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.buildFromMethod (InstanceBuilder.java:217)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.build (InstanceBuilder.java:158)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.PipelineRunner.fromOptions (PipelineRunner.java:55)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.create (Pipeline.java:155)
    at com.ford.datafactory.ingestion.streaming.StreamingPipeline.main (StreamingPipeline.java:41)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:282)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:834)
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build (SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild (SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build (CertPathBuilder.java:297)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild (PKIXValidator.java:434)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate (PKIXValidator.java:306)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate (Validator.java:264)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate (X509TrustManagerImpl.java:313)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted (X509TrustManagerImpl.java:222)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted (X509TrustManagerImpl.java:129)
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts (CertificateMessage.java:1341)
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate (CertificateMessage.java:1232)
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume (CertificateMessage.java:1175)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume (SSLHandshake.java:392)
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch (HandshakeContext.java:478)
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch (HandshakeContext.java:456)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch (TransportContext.java:199)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode (SSLTransport.java:171)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode (SSLSocketImpl.java:1369)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord (SSLSocketImpl.java:1278)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake (SSLSocketImpl.java:401)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake (SSLSocketImpl.java:373)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect (HttpsClient.java:567)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect (AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:197)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0 (HttpURLConnection.java:1367)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream (HttpURLConnection.java:1342)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream (HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:246)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute (NetHttpRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute (NetHttpRequest.java:84)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute (HttpRequest.java:1012)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.refreshAccessToken (ServiceAccountCredentials.java:609)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.refresh (OAuth2Credentials.java:164)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.getRequestMetadata (OAuth2Credentials.java:149)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.getRequestMetadata (ServiceAccountCredentials.java:946)
    at com.google.auth.http.HttpCredentialsAdapter.initialize (HttpCredentialsAdapter.java:91)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.ChainingHttpRequestInitializer.initialize (ChainingHttpRequestInitializer.java:52)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestFactory.buildRequest (HttpRequestFactory.java:91)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.buildHttpRequest (AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:404)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed (AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:514)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed (AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:455)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute (AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:565)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.ResilientOperation$AbstractGoogleClientRequestExecutor.call (ResilientOperation.java:171)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.ResilientOperation.retry (ResilientOperation.java:67)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.util.GcsUtil.getBucket (GcsUtil.java:489)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.util.GcsUtil.bucketAccessible (GcsUtil.java:477)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.util.GcsUtil.bucketAccessible (GcsUtil.java:450)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.storage.GcsPathValidator.verifyPathIsAccessible (GcsPathValidator.java:83)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.storage.GcsPathValidator.validateOutputFilePrefixSupported (GcsPathValidator.java:53)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.fromOptions (DataflowRunner.java:285)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.buildFromMethod (InstanceBuilder.java:217)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.build (InstanceBuilder.java:158)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.PipelineRunner.fromOptions (PipelineRunner.java:55)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.create (Pipeline.java:155)
    at com.ford.datafactory.ingestion.streaming.StreamingPipeline.main (StreamingPipeline.java:41)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:282)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:834)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  01:47 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-09-12T19:12:20-07:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (default-cli) on project ingestion-streaming: An exception occured while executing the Java class. Unable to verify that GCS bucket gs://bucket_name exists.: Error getting access token for service account: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

I have logged in to GCP from terminal using gcloud auth login and set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to the service account

I have tried to run this in a different machine and it works, therefore the bucket exists, the service account has owner access.

Any help to resolve this is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS  to the service account or to the path of the key file?

Comment: I have tried this but with no success. Could the company's proxy or firewall create this issue ?

Comment: In order to discard if it's an issue related with the proxy could you please confirm me from where what machine you are running it with no issues and which gives you the issue?

Comment: If you are behind a proxy did you set it up in your Maven settings?